# You do not have access to any management group. Please create one in the Azure portal and try to deploy again

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-bicep

I'm the owner of multiple subscriptions and multiple management groups within which these subscriptions are contained.

I want to use BICEP to deploy resources across several subscriptions within a management group. When I scope to subscription, I have no issues with this. Now I'm scoping to management group, I'm hitting a problem.

I am using VSCODE and logged into the correct Azure account

When I deploy my bicep file, I get the error below. This is shown after the 'search bar' in VSCODE has displayed all my subscriptions and when it's searching for my management groups.

> You do not have access to any management group. Please create one in
> the Azure portal and try to deploy again

**What additional permissions beyond the owner of the management group do I need?**

A simple example code is below.

***main.bicep***

```
targetScope='managementGroup'

module deployCoreResourceGroup 'createResourceGroup.bicep' = {
  scope: subscription(subscriptionIdCoreHub)
  name: resourceGroupCoreName
  params: {
    location: location
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroupCoreName
  }
}
```

***createResourceGroup.bicep***

```
param location string
param resourceGroupName string

targetScope = 'subscription'

resource resourceGroupCore 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2022-09-01' = {
  name: resourceGroupName
  location: location
}
```

Image showing I am the owner of a management group.

[image: managementgroup]

Comment: Have you cross checked that you are owner of the management group or subscription? @Damo

Comment: @Jahnavi yes, I am the owner of many management groups and all the subscriptions under them.

Comment: Ya ok can you use this command in VScode terminal [`az account management-group subscription add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account/management-group/subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-management-group-subscription-add) and set the required mangement group with subscription and try deploying the code once. @Damo

Comment: @Jahnavi I found the problem. I had the additional step of needing to AZ LOGIN within VS Code terminal. When previously working at the subscription level, I only needed to login to Azure from within the VSCODE UI. It seems to populate the Management Groups, I also need to login via the terminal.

Comment: Yes you need to login via VSCode terminal if you are deploying with it. @Damo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You do not have access to any management group. Please create one in the Azure portal and try to deploy again: -

*As discussed in the comments, providing a detail way below on how to resolve your issue.*

If you are deploying bicep code from `Visual Studio Code`, make sure that the Azure account `sign in` settings and account `credentials` are properly set to the relevant management group and subscription.

Go to `VScode >> Terminal` >> use [`az account management-group`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account/management-group/subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-management-group-subscription-add) command as shown below to set the above.

```bash
 az account management-group subscription add --name  xxx --subscription xxx
```

Also run `az login` command from the `VScode` terminal as it is very needed before deploying any code.

[image]

*Note:* Also check if you have necessary permissions to deploy the bicep into the corresponding Azure Management group.

After executing the above, I tried the same code as you and was able to deploy it successfully as shown below.

```bash
param  location  string = 'eastus'
param  resourceGroupName  string = 'newrgj'
targetScope = 'subscription'
resource  resourceGroupCore  'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2022-09-01' = {
    name: resourceGroupName
    location: location
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]